# ipaddress.py getting errors on a valid ip address

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running python 2.7. I downloaded the raw of ipaddress.py (https://github.com/phihag/ipaddress) . I tried to run a test to validate the ip address per the example. But even valid ip addresses seem to be invalid.

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('127.0.0.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ipaddress.py", line 163, in ip_address
    ' a unicode object?' % address)
ipaddress.AddressValueError: '127.0.0.1' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ipaddress.py", line 163, in ip_address
    ' a unicode object?' % address)
ipaddress.AddressValueError: '192.168.0.1' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/phihag/ipaddress/blob/master/README.md):

> Note that as in Python 3.3+ you must use character strings and not
>   byte strings for textual IP address representations:

I double checked it, and using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` allows you to skip the `u` in `u'make_me_unicode_string'`.

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('127.0.0.1')
IPv4Address(u'127.0.0.1')
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a `unicode` string. You can do it like this:

```
ipaddress.ip_address(u'192.168.0.1')
```

or

```
ipaddress.ip_address(unicode('192.168.0.1'))
```